# In defining the derivative, what definition of a limit is being used?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives, definition

The following definition of the derivative of a function is taken from Analysis on Manifolds by James Munkres:

[image]

Now what I'm confused about is what definition of a limit is being used above. There are two definitions that I'm familiar with from analysis

> **Definition (Limit of a function):** Let $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$ be metric spaces. Suppose that $E \subseteq X$. Let $f : E \to Y$ and suppose that $p$ is a limit point of $E$. We say that $$\lim_{x \to p} f(x) = q$$ is there exists a $q \in Y$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $$0 < d_X(x, p) < \delta \implies d_Y((f(x), q) < \epsilon$$ for any $x \in B_{(X, d_x)}(p, \delta)$
>
> **Definition (Limit of a sequence):** We say that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (X, d)$ converges to $x' \in X$ and write $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x'$$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a  natural number $N > 0$ such that $d(x_n, x') < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$

I'm sure that the author must be using the limit (of a function) in the definition of a derivative. Now what I'm confused about is that there is no domain specified for the new function $f : \ ? \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(t) = \frac{\phi(a+t) -\phi(a)}{t}$$ and also I have no way to tell if $0$ is actually a limit point for the domain of this new function.

What is the domain of this new function (which is being used in the definition of the derivative)?

---

**Update**: Based on the comments below I understand the following: If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $\phi : A \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function and $A$ contains a neighborhood $U$ of the point $a$ then we define the derivative of $\phi$ at $a$ by the equation $$\phi'(a) = \lim_{t \to 0} f(t)$$ where $f : B(a, r) \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $$f(t) =  \frac{\phi(a+t) -\phi(a)}{t}$$ and $r$ is some real number greater than $0$ such that the open ball $B(a, r) \subseteq U$.

Now the only problem with the above definition of a derivative is that by the definition of a limit of a function we need $0$ to be a limit point of $B(a, r)$ but it may be the case that $0$ is not a limit point of $B(a, r)$. (To see why note that by the definition of $B(a, r)$ we have $B(a, r) = (a-r, a+r)$ and we could have $a = 50$ and $r=1$ for example)

So how exactly does one apply the definition of a limit of a function to define the definition of the derivative of a function?

Comment: It is defined for all $t\neq 0$ such that $a+t$ belong to the neighborhood of $a$.

Comment: @N74 Also is the "neighborhood of $a$" an open set $U \subseteq A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (the parent space) containing $a$ or is $U$ open in the subspace $A$? (Sidenote if you'd like to turn your comment into an answer I shall accept it)

Comment: I'm assuming that $U$ must be open in $\mathbb{R}$ as opposed to the subspace $A$ because then we could have all kinds of wacky domains (e.g a discrete subset of $[0, 1]$ for the the function $f$ in which case the derivative wouldn't even exist (because the limit wouldn't even exist). In that case we can only take the derivative of functions that are defined on "nice-ish" sets. Am I correct in this observation?

Comment: Comment to the update. $f : B(0, r) \to \mathbb{R}$ as $t+a \in B(a,r)$.

Comment: @N74 I figured that out a while back just after I updated the question and didn't have time to re-update, sorry. Thanks for answering my questions!